# request.getAttribute returning null in servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

In jsp I have written following code:

```
    <form action="./ssoServlet?from=amount" method="post">
    <%request.setAttribute("formName", "DayCareForm"); %>
    Amount  
     <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" required >
     <button onclick="dayCarePdf()" type="submit"> Convert to PDF </button>
    </form>
```

Post method of servlet is:

```
@Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("DoPost method");
        resp.setContentType("text/html");

        if(req.getParameter("from").equals("amount"))
        {
            req.getParameter("amount");

            String form = (String) req.getAttribute("formName");
            System.out.println("Type of form " +req.getAttribute("formName"));
            RequestDispatcher dispature = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/DayCare.jsp");
            dispature.forward(req, resp);
        }
}
```

However, The servlet is returning null value for type of form

Comment: how are you submitting form?

Comment: I have a button inside form                                                          <button onclick="dayCarePdf()" type="submit"> Convert to PDF </button>

Comment: i cant see any submit button over there

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: in your daycare() write below code document.getElementById("YOUR FORM ID ").submit(); and remove  this ?from=amount

Comment: because onClick will directly go to the dayCare() function it wont sumbit a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

```
<form action="./ssoServlet" method="post" id="myForm" name="DayCareForm">
Amount  
 <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" required >
 <input type="hidden" name="formName" value="DayCareForm" />
<button onclick="dayCarePdf()" type="submit"> Convert to PDF </button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function dayCarePdf()
{
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();

//Rest Code will come here


}
```

set a hidden field as form name and you can access form name by below code.

```
   String formName= request.getParameter ("formName");  // you will get DayCareForm as we set form name
```

Comment: Submit is a button and not textfield

Comment: but in your code  i can see text box only, not a button, try my code

Comment: I want the "formName" in servlet and not javascript

Comment: check you can get form name by setting hidden field in form

Comment: But it will add a textfield in my form.

Comment: it doesn't matter its also a way to send some hidden value to servlet. its recommended

Comment: setting attribute and sending hidden text value is same way.

Comment: Yes!It worked ... Added the hidden field

Comment: Great, if it works then please accept my answer. :)

Comment: Accept my answer by selecting  tick symbol over up and down arrow.

Comment: There is an tick symbol to accept the answer, you require 15 reputation to upvote the answer, for accepting answer you wont require reputation.

Comment: good, let me know if you face any issue in future I'm also from pune. :) good luck then

Answer (score 1):

In the jsp You set a value in the request. So it works only for the life of the request.

The servlet is invoked before passing to the jsp. So when the attribute is retrieved from the request in the servlet it doesn't exist yet.

Put it in the session and it works.

---

When you reach the line:

```
String form = (String) request.getAttribute("formName");
```

a code

```
req.setAttribute("formName", something)
```

has not been set for the **current** request.

The code

```
<%request.setAttribute("formName", "DayCareForm"); %>
```

is performed on the **previous** request. Each time you pass to the servlet the request attributes are reset.

But you can set an attribute and retrieve an attribute from the session. In this case it works because a session ends when the browser is closed or the session is invalidated.

---

To work with a session, instead of a request replace

```
<%request.setAttribute("formName", "DayCareForm"); %>
```

with

```
<%session.setAttribute("formName", "DayCareForm"); %>
```

and

```
String form = (String) request.getAttribute("formName");
```

with

```
String form = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("formName");
```

Comment: Could u please support your answer with code

Comment: I understood the problem now. So now i should add session.getAttribute("formName") ?

Comment: I have changed my code to whatever u have suggested. But i am still getting null

Comment: @RadhikaKulkarni Yes, as you can see in the bottom part of the answer.

Comment: @RadhikaKulkarni The code of the jsp is executed before the Servlet? In the jsp you set the attribute formName (in the session, not in the request)?

Comment: Yes. Jsp is executed first. In jsp i set attribute formName

Comment: @RadhikaKulkarni are you sure that you set it on the session?

Comment: Yes i have changed it

Comment: @RadhikaKulkarni have you redeployed the war? Jsp modification are taken also without redeploying the war, but servlet modifications are not.

Comment: type casting is not a solution.earlier she has not submitting the form.

Comment: Hey!Thanx a lot.. I have used hidden value method and it worked